# Copy image from one folder to another - Android

Tags: android, android-file, onactivityresult, filechannel

Hi Everyone I am trying to copy an image from one folder to another which user selects from the gallery. It's not throwing any error as well. Please check the below code.

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String fileName = "";

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            try {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                switch (cameraNo) {
                    case 1:
                        Bitmap bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                        imageBtn1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                        reduceImageSize(path);
                        fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
              try {
                            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                            if (sd.canWrite()) {

                                String destinationImagePath= "/MyImages/file.jpg";
                                File source= new File(path);
                                File destination= new File(sd, destinationImagePath);
                                if (source.exists()) {
                                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                                    src.close();
                                    dst.close();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                        imageArrayList.add(path);
                        imageNameList.add(fileName);

                        break;

   }}
```

Answer (score 3):

this is working for me, give it a try ;):

```
public static void copyFile(String inputPath, String outputPath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

        // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        LOGGER.debug("Copied file to " + outputPath);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        LOGGER.error(fnfe1.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: are you passing the correct paths? 

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + [yourDir/yourFile.yourExtension]; ?

Answer (score 3):

if you have a source path and destination path then try this one

```
    /**
     * copy contents from source file to destination file
     * 
     * @param sourceFilePath  Source file path address
     * @param destinationFilePath Destination file path address
     */
    private void copyFile(File sourceFilePath, File destinationFilePath) {

        try{

            if (!sourceFilePath.exists()) {
            return;
            }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFilePath).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destinationFilePath).getChannel();
        if (destination != null && source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

All the best

Comment: If you are using the path instead of File then make sure to convert your path into the File type first and then execute the above code.
It will work fine)))